# Error on Category Page

Tags: magento2, php, blocks, magento2.2.6

> I am getting error on Category Page Magento 2.2.6 ( Element 'block',
>   attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed)
>
> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block',
>   attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed. Line: 1018

After removing one theme then I am getting this error.
Please help me

Comment: are you using any .xml file on category page?

Comment: I think any catalog_category_view.xml file have the remove attribute in <block>, if you want to remove any block you must need to use <referenceBlock>.